# Deserialization of nested list with attributes

Tags: c#, xml

I'm currently trying to deserialize the following XML file in C#.
The problem is that the second list `TraceLinkOrder` that should contain the order positions is not being properly deserialized.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tli:AddTracelinkOrders xmlns:tli="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/CarismaIntegration" xmlns:x50="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x50020">
 <tli:carismaOrders>
  <x50:TracelinkOrder DocType="0" Annulation="false" TROrderType="1" Department="08">
   <x50:TracelinkOrderLine NetValue="42.00" AccountNo="100206" LineNo="10000"/>
   <x50:TracelinkOrderLine NetValue="259.17" AccountNo="100306" LineNo="20000"/>
   <x50:TracelinkOrderLine NetValue="385.80" AccountNo="100406" LineNo="30000"/>
  </x50:TracelinkOrder>
  <x50:TracelinkOrder DocType="1" Annulation="false" TROrderType="1" Department="08">
   <x50:TracelinkOrderLine NetValue="2.10" AccountNo="100206" LineNo="10000"/>
   <x50:TracelinkOrderLine NetValue="25.92" AccountNo="100306" LineNo="20000"/>
  </x50:TracelinkOrder>
 </tli:carismaOrders>
</tli:AddTracelinkOrders>
```

Parent class

```
[XmlRoot("AddTracelinkOrders", Namespace = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/CarismaIntegration")]
public class TraceLinkOrders
{
    [XmlArray("carismaOrders", Namespace = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/CarismaIntegration")]
    [XmlArrayItem("TracelinkOrder", Namespace = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x50020")]
    public List<TraceLinkOrder> CarismaOrders { get; set; }
}
```

Order

```
[XmlRoot("TracelinkOrder")]
public class TraceLinkOrder
{
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public Int16 DocType { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public Boolean Annulation { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public Int16 TROrderType { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public Int16 Department { get; set; }
}
```

Order line

```
[XmlRoot("TracelinkOrderLine", Namespace = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x50020")]
public class TraceLinkOrderLine
{
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public Decimal NetValue { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public String AccountNo { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public String LineNo { get; set; }
}
```

The order class should contain a list of order lines.
I have tried to add a property to the order class like this:

```
[XmlArrayItem("TracelinkOrderLine", Namespace = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x50020")]
public List<TraceLinkOrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
```

Unfortunately that list is always empty.

Another idea i had was to make `TraceLinkOrder` extend `List<TraceLinkOrderLine>` but that doesn't work either.

```
[XmlRoot("TracelinkOrder")]
public class TraceLinkOrder : List<TraceLinkOrderLine>
```

When i do that the `CarismaOrders` list is empty.

How can i deserialize this XML file while still being able to access all attributes of the elements `TraceLinkOrder` and `TraceLinkOrderLine` ?

Comment: it looks like you have two lists in the xml, but your class has only one.

Comment: Yes I'm missing the second list because i don't know how to add that in my code. Any Ideas ?

Comment: since the second list doesn't have a direct parent (unique list name)  you need to do it manually or change the xml

Comment: As far as i know changing the xml is not possible since its created by some other program. With manually you mean using an XmlDocument and accessing the nodes directly ?

Comment: Yes. because the list is splitted by the `DocType` attribute.

Comment: It is not an ArrayList.  An Array list has two level of XML tags.  So use XmlElement : [XmlElement("TracelinkOrderLine", Namespace = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x50020")]
public List<TraceLinkOrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }

Comment: @jdweng Thank you that does the trick. Do you mind creating an answer with that so i can accept that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jdweng pointed out in the comments of my question the trick is to use the`XmlElement`attribute instead of the`XmlArrayItem`.
This will tell C# to take all elements of that name and form a list with them.

The final code for the `TraceLinkOrder` class looks like this:

```
[XmlRoot("TracelinkOrder")]
public class TraceLinkOrder
{
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public Int16 DocType { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public Boolean Annulation { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public Int16 TROrderType { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public Int16 Department { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("TracelinkOrderLine")]
    public List<TraceLinkOrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}
```